# How to manage my Favorites list, and delete old ones?

Tags: support, profile-page, bookmarks

Is there a simple way to go into my Favorites list and delete old ones I no longer want?

I have only tried random things, and don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your [Favorites list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites), first sort by "added" so you can see the oldest in the last pages:

> [image: favorites sort options]

Now go to the last page(s) where you can simply click the star icon to unfavorite a question:

> [image: sample favorite questions with stars highlighted]

Worth to mention that on this list, the star icon has no tooltip, so it's not trivial to guess.